# Poker Game Java Logic Error

Tags: java

```
if (first == 11)    
{card1s = "Jack";
}else {
if (second == 11)   
{card2s = "Jack";
} else {
if (third == 11)    
{card3s = "Jack";
}
 else {
if (fourth == 11)   
{card4s = "Jack";
  }
else {
if (fifth == 11)    
{card5s = "Jack";
  }
else {
if (first == 12)    
{card1s = "Queen";
  }
else {
if (second == 12)   
{card2s = "Queen";
  }
else {
if (third == 12)    
{card3s = "Queen";
  }
else {
if (fourth == 12)   
{card4s = "Queen";
  }
else {
if (fifth == 12)    
{card5s = "Queen";
  }
else {
if (first == 13)    
{card1s = "King";
  }
else {
if (second == 13)   
{card2s = "King";
  }
else {
if (third == 13)    
{card3s = "King";
  }
else {
if (fourth == 13)   
{card4s = "King";
  }
else {
if (fifth == 13)        
{card1s = "King";
  }
else {
if (first == 1) 
{card1s = "Ace";
  }
else {
if (second == 1)    
{card2s = "Ace";
  }
else {
if (third == 1) 
{card3s = "Ace";
  }
else {
if (fourth == 1)    
{card4s = "Ace";
  }
else {
if (fifth == 1) 
{card5s = "Ace";
 }
 else {
 card1s = null;
 card2s = null;
 card3s = null;
 card4s = null;
 card5s = null;
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
    if ((first >= 11) | (first == 1))
System.out.println("The first card is:  " + card1s + first);
```

This is part of my poker game program that is used to translate card in words (ex. 11 is a Jack and 12 is a Queen), the result should be printing out the translated word along with the number that is used to determine the word. The program compiles without issue, but the problem is, when I run this program, it would come up with "The first card is: Jack13" or "Queen13" things like that.

Comment: First learn the `else if` operator and indent properly. It'll save you so many curly braces and you'll have less lines of code http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: I have a horrible feeling you shouldn't have made all those `if`s like that. Perhaps this will give you some ideas... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I use lots of if and else because I find myself getting a lot of "else without if" errors when using else if. Learn that some other time :)

Comment: make a class for your cards. maybe something like: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/37674/11700

Comment: This is the stuff of nightmares!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of duplicate code, and a `switch` is more apporpriate here. Also you should use methods. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
    String card1s = getCardAsString(first);
    // ...
    if ((first >= 11) || (first == 1))
    System.out.println("The first card is:  " + card1s + first);
}

private static String getCardAsString(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 1:
        return "Ace";
    case 11:
        return "Jack";
    case 12:
        return "Queen";
    case 13:
        return "King";
    default:
        return String.valueOf(i); // or return null; not sure what you need
    }
}
```

With `if`s:

```
private static String getCardAsString2(int i) {
    if (i == 1)
        return "Ace";
    if (i == 11)
        return "Jack";
    if (i == 12)
        return "Queen";
    if (i == 13)
        return "King";
    return String.valueOf(i);// or return null;
}
```

Comment: .. and Enums to prevent typos